# Кликабельная иконка WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi

Как разместить на форме кликабельную иконку и обработать нажатие на нее? Или создать кнопку и поменять у нее иконку? Сделать как-то через ресурсы

Comment: Создавайте Static контрол, рисуйте на нем иконку, обрабатывайте сообщения мыши. В принципе, это же можно делать и с основным окном.